# How to check if an embed video is ended using WebView in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, webview

I could embedded a video form youTube in my Application using a WebView successfully. 
My problem is that I wanted to check if the video is ended or not. In fact, I want to trigger a js function when the video is going to be ended. Is there any way to detect that the video is going to be ended in the WebView in react native. Here is my small code:

```
<WebView
    style={this.state.position == 'vertical' ? styles.VidoeContainer : styles.VidoeContainerHorizental}
    javaScriptEnabled={true}
    domStorageEnabled={true}
    source={{ uri: "https://www.youtube.com/embed/1iccpf2eN1Q" }}
/>
```

If there is no way, can you please tell me any alternative to do that. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Rather than a webview component if possible you can try https://github.com/inProgress-team/react-native-youtube component. It has a prop `onChangeState` that fires multiple events like `buffering/playing/paused` .

Comment: @SagarKhan: Thanks for your answer. But this component has a weakness in my opinion. It needs the official YouTube app installed on the phone. So if a user doesn't have it, he will have a problem. As it is written in its documentation --->
(IMPORTANT! (Android Only): The Android implementation of this component needs to have the official YouTube app installed on the device. Otherwise the user will be prompted to install / activate the app, and an error event will be triggered with SERVICE_MISSING/SERVICE_DISABLED.)